# How can I import a multi-value, multi-level dimension into EazyBI?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have a custom field I want to import into a dimension in eazyBI. On each issue, this field contains several values separated by semicolons (";"). I can get these values to split and import into a dimension no problem.

Here is what I need help with. The individual values in my field are City, Country pairs. So on an issue in Jira, this custom field might contain a string like "Zurich, Switzerland; London, United Kingdom; Paris, France". I want to import these as multi-level values so that they each go into the dimension under City/Country levels. Right now, all I can manage is to import them as a list of single-level "City, Country" strings.

If I add `levels = ["Country", "City"]` and `multiple_values = true` at the same time, when I run an import I get a syntax error from the database.

This is what I have:

```
[jira.customfield_destinations]
name = "Destinations"
data_type = "string"
dimension = true
check_calculated_value = true  # for debugging, remove when everything works
multiple_values = true
levels = ["Country", "City"]
javascript_code = '''
if (issue.fields.customfield_12655) {
  const table = issue.fields.customfield_12655
                     .split('; ')
                     .map(function (s) { return s.split(', ').reverse(); });

  issue.fields.customfield_destinations = table;
}
'''
```

This is what I get on import:

[image: Error message]

Is this not supported by the tool, or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such combination of configuration parameters is not supported in eazyBI currently. eazyBI cannot read this combination from the array of arrays to tell that you need multiple levels and multiple values.

Alternatively, you can generate the string of listed values, but, for the multiple levels and multiple value fields, you need to provide the delimiter in the split_by parameter. Currently, for both options, the delimiter parameter is with the same name "split_by"; it is not possible to cheat it somehow to cover both options.

Kindly,

Janis, eazyBI support

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like I will have to find another way. Please consider supporting something like this in a future version.